# Picks last files for download and skips above one in Json UITableview Alamofire Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I have implemented a download manager and its downloading files accordingly. 
The structure is like `one Date have multiple appointments` and `one appointment have detailed information` which consists of `multiple pdf files` for download.

- Problem I am facing when I start download it always pick only the last appointment files and skipped other ones.

I'm struggling with it and not getting an idea. Anyone please help me regarding this.

For example - specific date has four appointments it skips first three and pick the last one which is fourth one.

Github link for detailed code:
https://github.com/MasamMahmood/TestDownload

Data Services:

```
func pullData(){

        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Appointment", withExtension: "json") {
            do {

                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)
                self.Appdata = jsonData.appointments

                for i in Appdata! {
                    self.detailData(AppId: i.id ?? 0)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }

    }

    func detailData(AppId: Int){

        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AppointmentDetail", withExtension: "json") {
            do {

                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(AppointmentDetail.self, from: data)
                self.AppDetailData = jsonData

                for param in AppDetailData?.sectionList ?? [] {
                    for item in param.items! {

                        if item.actionType == 2 {
//                            let filename = item.actionUrl ?? ""
                            let url = item.actionUrl ?? ""
                            let filename = item.textField ?? ""

                            downloadInfos.append(ALDownloadInfo(url: url, name: filename))


                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }

    }
```

tableView Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DownloadEntryViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DownloadEntryViewCell
        let dic = Appdata?[indexPath.row]
        var stackHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
        cell.fileNameLabel.text = dic?.date


        for i in Appdata ?? [] {
            let child_view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FooterView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FooterView
            for j in downloadInfos {
            child_view.projName.text = i.projectName
            child_view.model = j
            child_view.model.stateChangeBlock = { [weak self] state in
                guard let weakself = self else {
                    return
                }
                print("stateChangeBlock == \(state)")
                if state == .Completed {


                    child_view.tipView.backgroundColor = child_view.footerProgress.tintColor
                     print("stateChangeBlock == \(state)")
                    let completeInfos = weakself.downloadInfos.filter{$0.state == ALDownloadState.Completed}
                    print( Float(completeInfos.count/weakself.downloadInfos.count))
                    cell.individualProgress.progress = Float(completeInfos.count)/Float(weakself.downloadInfos.count)
                    cell.progressLabel.text = "\( Float(completeInfos.count)/Float(weakself.downloadInfos.count)*100)"
                    cell.downloadURLLabel.text = "Downloading(\(Float(completeInfos.count)/Float(weakself.downloadInfos.count)))"

                }

            }

        }
        cell.stackViewFooter.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackHeight).isActive = true
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to show progress for each of the appointments or?

Comment: @Ladislav yes exactly. progress for each appointment.

Comment: So for appointment 1 "id": 15473453 -> What should be visible in table view cell and what downloads need to happen for appointment 1?

Comment: @Ladislav Actually I have used some test data in JSON files. But in actual Appointment id pass to Appointment detail to get the pdf files. I am displaying `Appointment project name` and progress of all files which are part of `appointmentDetail`
Using two xib - one main which display only appointment date and overall progress.
Second xib- is childview or footerview which has progress of files (appointmentDetail) and appointment projectname for display.

Comment: So lets say appointment 1 has 3 files, you would then if expanded the table view cell see 3 files below the cell and progress of each one?

Comment: @Ladislav it should be like this 
Date(today) -> display 3 appointments in expanded one -> all files merge progress.

`In shared project 
2020-02-06 header -> displays 4 appointments ( first - Melek Mosso) -> all files progress (from appointment detail) `

Comment: @Ladislav   overall both json files contains (appointment & appointment detail) one day appointment data. 
`I am using date on the top xib ( as a header) which is 2020-02-06 
and in Expanded cell second xib -> appointment - projectname (Melek Mosso) -> files progress bar merge one from appointmentDetails. `

you can check my json files.

Comment: Lets talk tomorrow and see what we can figure out

Comment: @Ladislav OK sure Thank you. I will message you again.

Comment: @Ladislav I am available here now, please do let me know when you available or any questions

Comment: @Ladislav Kindly possible if you're available.